# Best way for getting the indexes of matched objects in NSArray in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have the following two arrays.

```
 NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",@"DEF", nil];
 NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",@"123",@"DEF",@"DEF", nil];
```

Now i have to search each array1's object and in array2 and need to get the matched indexes.
And my application contains more than one thousand objects in array2.

Please suggest the best possible way other than putting second for loop in first for loop

```
for (int i=0; i<array1.count; i++)
{
//Need to search the [array1 objectAtIndex:i] string in array2 and need to get the matched indexes into an array in best optimised way here.

    NSMutableArray *matchedIndexesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *stringToSearch=[array1 objectAtIndex:i];

    //here i can put another array like below to get the matched indexes..but is there any optimized way other than this for loop here? or is there any simple inbuilt method to get the matched objects into an array here.
    for (int j=0; j<array2.count; j++)
    {
        if ([stringToSearch isEqualToString:[array2 objectAtIndex:j]])
        {
            [matchedIndexesArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",j]];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"matchedIndexesArray-->%@<--",matchedIndexesArray);
    //I will use this matchedIndexesArray here further processing...
    //
    //
    //
    //Large Code Here
    //
    //
    //

}
```

Comment: `[array1 indexOfObject:object]`, `[array2 indexOfObject:object]`

Comment: you need to get elements common in both arrays into an array? The result should be ("ABC","DEF")?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli, The question asks for the indices of the objects, not the objects themselves.

Comment: thanks @НаильГалиаскаров ..but i didn't get you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the NSSet documentation, membership testing is faster for *sets* than for *arrays*.
Therefore it makes sense to convert `array1` to a set first:

```
NSSet *set1 = [NSSet setWithArray:array1];
```

and then test each object of `array2` for membership in the set. This can be conveniently
done as

```
NSIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [array2 indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [set1 containsObject:obj];
}];
```

Show all matching indexes:

```
[matchingIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)idx);
}];
// Output: 0, 2, 3
```

---

**UPDATE:** (after question edit) No, there is no method to fill an `NSArray` with the indices of matching objects. But there is a method to fill an `NSIndexSet`. `NSIndexSet` is a special collection to store indices
into some other data structure, such as an array. Then your code would look like

```
for (NSString *stringToSearch in array1) {
    NSIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [array2 indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [stringToSearch isEqualToString:obj];
    }];

    NSLog(@"matchingIndexes: %@", matchingIndexes);

    // Work with matchingIndex, for example enumerate all indices:
    [matchingIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)idx);
    }];
}
```

But I do not know if it makes much difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks @Martin R...But I have to check the [array1 indexOfObject:i] with the all objects in array2 and need to store the matching indexes in another array in each iteration of the first loop as i have to use the matched indexes array for further process in each iteration of the first loop.

Comment: @Ashok: Then I misunderstood your question (it wasn't clear in the first version). So what should the resulting array be for your input data?

Comment: Because array1 contains 2 objects, The Resulting array should be (0) in first iteration, (2,3) in second iteration. Here the array should contain matching indexes in each iteration that's all.

Comment: @Ashok: I have updated the answer with a suggestion. But if you need an array, then there is probably no better alternative to what you already do.

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *a = @[@"123", @"456", @"ABC", @"DEF"];
NSArray *b = @[@"123", @"ABC", @"---"];

NSIndexSet *indexes = [a indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    return [b containsObject:obj]
}];

NSLog(@"%@", indexes);
```

Comment: It *may* not work for string literals. AFAIK, defined like that, two objects, @"ABC" and @"ABC" may not be the same pointer.

Comment: @JamesWebster: `containsObject:` uses `isEqual:` for testing, and that is equivalent to `isEqualToString:` for string objects.

Comment: Good to know. I didn't realise `isEqual:` and `isEqualToString:` were identical for strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *array1=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",@"DEF", nil];
    NSArray *array2=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ABC",@"123",@"DEF",@"DEF", nil];


    for (int i=0; i<array1.count; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<array2.count; j++) {
            if ([[array1 objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString: [array2 objectAtIndex:j]]) {
                NSLog(@"Matched Indexes %d %@", i, [array1 objectAtIndex:i] );
            }
        }
       }
```